# Truss Roofing System and Load Bearing Walls

Tags: structural-engineering

House built in the 50's uses a truss system to support the roof.  1 floor, about 24 feet wide.  Trusses are constructed all from 2 by 4s and placed 24" OC.

I would not think this would require a load bearing wall in the middle of the house, but there seems to be one?

I would like to know if it's possible to remove this wall without installing a beam.

Comment: Do you have a basement? If there is a beam with column supports in the middle then there is a bearing wall on top.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! I'm unclear as to what you're actually asking: do you want to know if such a truss would theoretically require a load-bearing wall or simply how to determine if the existing wall is load-bearing? Please [edit] your question to clarify. Also, if you're thinking of maybe removing the wall, then the first question is actually irrelevant: if it is load-bearing, then you have to assume the engineer took the wall into consideration, meaning it's a critical structural component that cannot be trivially removed (even if such a truss could be done without a load-bearing wall).

Comment: @r13 There is a basement, and there is an I beam running down the middle of the basement.  However, and I'm not trying to be difficult, but wouldn't the beam in the basement be more about supporting the load of the floor and what's on it rather than supporting the roof directly?  I'm just trying to learn here, and it wouldn't be my impression that a wall built on top of such a beam would necessarily automatically be load bearing.

Comment: @Wasabi Thank you for the welcome!  Yes, my question was sort of muddled.  I haven't decided if I really want to remove the wall yet or not, so I didn't state it explicitly that way.  Part of this is just my desire to become more knowledgeable in general.  From what I read, it seems strongly suggested in a lot of places that when a roof truss is used only the walls on either end of the truss are load bearing, which leads me to believe this wall may not be load bearing, but I can see how it might be depending on the design parameters of the truss itself.

Comment: The beam below is a red flag unless the trusses do not bear on the wall. An Internet forum is not the place to learn structural mechanics which can jeopardize your safety.